# Saving Table Counts as a Vector

Tags: r

I am trying to loop through a sequence of values and save my table count results in a separate vector or matrix. I'm new to programming so please excuse the poor attempt.

Here is my problem:

```
pred_test <- seq(0, 1, length=1000)
test$PURCHASER_FLAG <- sample(c(0,1), size=1000, replace= TRUE)
crit = seq(from=0, to=1, by=.01)

list <- matrix(0, nrow=101, ncol=2)

for (i in 1:length(crit)) {
list[i,] <- as.numeric(table(pred_test >= i, test$PURCHASER_FLAG)[2,])

}
```

I want to loop through all the values of crit and save the results of each associated table count as a row in a new vector called 'list'. Pred_test is a probability score from 0-1 and Purchaser flag is the associated class of 0 or 1. 
I want to save these counts for each associated critical thresholds in crit.

Please let me know if there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: What is `pred_test` and `test$PURCHASER_FLAG`? Please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Use `sapply` and ensure that the dimensions of all the tables you generate are the same (2 x 2) in your case:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


# generate the data
df_foo = data_frame(
  pred_test = runif(1000),
  PURCHASER_FLAG = sample(c(0, 1), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
)

# collect the confusion matrices 
m_confusion = sapply(
  seq(0, 1, .1), function(x) { 
    # straighten out the matrix
    as.numeric(
      # create the confusion matrix
      table(
        # ensure that all the levels are always represented
        factor(
          df_foo$pred_test > x, levels = c("TRUE", "FALSE")
        ), 
        df_foo$PURCHASER_FLAG
      )
    )
  }
)

# add some dimnames to the matrix created
colnames(m_confusion) = seq(0, 1, 0.1)

# create the rownames from a dummy object
rownames_confusion = 
  unite(
    expand.grid(
      dimnames(
        table(
          factor(
            df_foo$pred_test > 0.1, levels = c("TRUE", "FALSE")), df_foo$PURCHASER_FLAG
        )
      )
    ), rownames, everything()
  )$rownames

# attach the rownames
rownames(m_confusion) = rownames_confusion

# print the final object
m_confusion
```

This gives:

```
> m_confusion
          0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9   1
TRUE_0  510 467 425 376 318 274 210 157 103  52   0
FALSE_0   0  43  85 134 192 236 300 353 407 458 510
TRUE_1  490 428 374 326 284 246 205 158 111  54   0
FALSE_1   0  62 116 164 206 244 285 332 379 436 490
```

I am sure there is an easier way to create the row dimnames, but I leave that to you to figure out.